# YA book series about alien teenagers who (maybe) time travel on Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Looking for the name of this book series from the 90s or early aughts, and I can't remember the title, the author, or any of the characters names.
What I *can* remember is that one of the girls had four arms, and on one of the covers she's dressed as a pirate, swinging on a rope.  I remember that much because she was my favorite.

I don't remember if they were *actually* time-traveling or if it was a holodeck kind of situation, or why they were learning about Earth (unless, of course, they were trapped there via a faulty time travel device)

The other thing I remember is that there were Os in the title, because they were saturns/ringed planets on the covers.

ETA: something I remembered this morning: the books came with a sheet of temporary tattoos in them, which was a new big thing at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking for that book series as well, and I finally found it! I think the specific book you're thinking of is *[All Hands On Deck](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/all-hands-on-deck-goners_jamie-simons_ew-scollon/2440971/#isbn=0380797321&idiq=30189360)*, part of the *Goners* series by Jamie Simons and E.W. Scollon

[image: Book cover for *All Hands on Deck*]

> The cosmic rescue team of Xela and Arms Akimbo, searching for a Goner among the sailing ships of the Canary Islands in 1492, find themselves aboard the Santa Maria and pursue suspicions surrounding Christopher Columbus. Original.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you explain why you believe this matches the book described in the question?

Comment: Oops, my bad! Why I think this is the book mentioned in the post: The cover is a 4-armed gal dressed as a pirate swinging on a rope, as mentioned in the post. The series is about a group of alien teens who travel through a wormhole to different times and places on Earth. The books also have an O in the title with the Saturn-esque rings, as DryadGurrl described, and at least some of the books in the series came with temporary tattoos. It was also published in the time frame given in the post.

Comment: Yep, looks like a pretty good match. Thanks!

Comment: That's the one!  Though how I could have forgotten that the character's name was 'Arms Akimbo' I have no idea.